# Error: Do not pass children as props. Instead, nest children between the opening and closing tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have found a similar issue online but the solutions havent helped my course. I am new to typescript and so I assume I could be missing something very simple. I have a simple app on Nextjs. It renders fine but I get this error when I try to build it locally:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import Sidebar from './sidebar';
import LayoutContent from './layout_content';

type Props = {
  children: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[]
}
const Layout = ({ children }: Props) => {
  

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
  const toggle = () => {
    setOpen(!open)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar onClick={toggle} sidebar={open} />

      <LayoutContent children={children} sidebar={open}/>
     
    </>
  )
}

export default Layout;
```

**layout_content.tsx**

```
const LayoutContent = ({ children , sidebar}: {children:any, sidebar:any}) => {
      return(
      <>
          <div>
              {children}
          </div>
      </>
)}
```

Comment: Hey [@siderra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14287707/siderra) it's that your error ```Property 'children' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Props'.``` if it is. then you can you use this, but I not recommend you. ```children?: JSX.Element | JSX.Element[]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not pass a **react node** to layout content as props. you can just wrap children inside layout content component.

**layout_content.tsx**

```
import React from "react";

const LayoutContent = ({ children , sidebar}: {children:React.ReactNode, sidebar:boolean}) => {
      return(
      <div>
         {children}
      </div>
   )}
```

**in your main layout**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import Sidebar from './sidebar';
import LayoutContent from './layout_content';

type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode
}
const Layout = ({ children }: Props) => {
  

  const [open, setOpen] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const toggle = () => {
    setOpen(!open)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar onClick={toggle} sidebar={open} />

      <LayoutContent sidebar={open}>
          {children}
      </LayoutContent>

    </>
  )
}

export default Layout;
```

Answer (score 2):

It tells you not to pass children prop into your LayoutContent.
To pass children, you should just put all you need between opening and closing tags of LayoutContent component, like this

```
<LayoutContent sidebar={open}>
  {children}
</LayoutContent>
```

Or even higher where you pass children to Layout component